# アンドロイドのListViewの背景について

Tags: java, android, android-listfragment

Android Studio で開発をしていますが、始めて間もないのでわからないことだらけです。
どうか知識を貸してください。

現在ListViewでの背景を動的に変更したいと考えています(ゼブラカラーに変更)。

ただ、ネット上の先人達のサンプルを多数確認しましたが、解決できない問題点がいくつかあるので箇条書きにしていきます。

・AppcompatActivityを継承している(ターゲットバージョンを古く設定している、また新しい機能も使いたい)のでArrayAdapter<>を継承できない。

⇒getViewをオーバーライドして int position を持ってくることができない。

・動的に背景を変更したいので指定して変更ではなくif分岐で処理したい。
⇒int position が必要になってくる

(ex)

```
if(position%2==0){
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}else{
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

など

・そのほかのサンプルにあった getItemAtPosition などを利用しようとも考えたが利用できなかった。

positionだけを獲得する方法はあるのでしょうか？また、無理にpositionを獲得しなくても、このような処理を施すことはできるのでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

以下サンプルを付け加えました。

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 final String[] baseArray = {"ApplePie", "BananaBread", "CupCake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo", "GingerBread", "Honeycomb", "IcecreamSandwich",
        "JellyBean", "KitKat", "Lollipop", "Marshmallow"};

ListView list1;
Button btn1;
int position;
String item;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    findView();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, baseArray);

    list1.setAdapter(adapter);

 /*if (position % 2 == 0) {
        list1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(100, 100, 100));
    } else {
        list1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }*/
}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void findView() {

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Javaを理解されていないように見受けられます。とりあえず実装しているAdapterクラスを貼り付けてもらえませんか？

Comment: サンプルソース追加しました。
現状ではAdapter ではなくAppcompatActivity　を実装しています。
お手数ですがよろしくお願いします

Comment: ありがとうございます。Adapterクラスを自分で実装されていないことがわかったので回答作成します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ネット上の先人達のサンプルでは、`Adapter`クラスを継承したものを各自実装しています。

1 new -> Java classで`MainActivity`と同じパッケージに`MyAdapter.java`を追加する。

2 次のように、`ArrayAdapter<String>`を継承させる。コンストラクタなど、必要なものを作る。

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    // コンストラクタ
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects){
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }
    // ここに、getView()などを記述する
}
```

3  `MainActivity`側で、次のように`MyAdapter`を使用するよう書き換える。

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, baseArray);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。お蔭様で大方の方針が見えてきました！

細かなエラーとして、baseArray　がarrayとして定義しているのに対して、コンストラクタのMyAdapter での引数がList型で定義されているところがエラーになってしまいます。

そこは、もう少し頑張って改善したいと思います。

Comment: Arrays.asList で配列をリスト化し、無事できました！
ありがとうございました。まだまだ始めたばかりですが、より一層勉強していこうかと思います。いろいろとありがとうございました！

Comment: String[]を引数にしたい場合はコンストラクタ側を直したほうがよさそうですね。幸いにも`ArrayAdapter<T>`には`T[]`版もあるので。

Comment: 言われた通り String[] objects でも書き直し、問題ないことを確認しました。引数などをしっかり確認することで、利用できる型の幅を広げていきたいと思います。